# html5 drag and drop wit multiple types

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I want to drag text selections along with files, img & a tags into a drop area. Im pretty new to html5 dnd. Any help at all would be appreciated. Even if its a reference to a solution some where on the web. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good introduction :

http://html5demos.com/drag

(click "view source")

But you'll see there are problems and limits, especially if you try to drag things that aren't links on IE. This isn't yet a perfect and mature technology (but I like to use it as it really can enhance some web applications ergonomy).